# Laravel Eager Loading Results Not Fiultering, Also Returning Null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am writing an Eloquent query. The condition is as follows:

1. There are four tables:

   1. Table 1: `medicare_advantage_table`
   2. Table 2: `medicare_advantage_plan_table`
   3. Table 3: `medicare_advantage_features_table`
   4. Table 4: `medicare_advantage_company_table`
2. Table 1 has `ManyToMany` relation with Table 3 via `medicare_advantage_features_pivot` table
3. Table 1 has `ManyToOne` relation with Table 2
4. Table 1 has `ManyToOne` relation with Table 4

Now I want to query all the records from `medicare_advantage_table` provided `medicare_advantage_plan_id`, `medicare_advantage_company_id` and `medicare_advantage_features_id` as arrays. I have written this eloquent query. It is fetching all the records from `medicare_advantage_table` without constraining and selecting from other three tables like this:

[Result Set Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuoFn.png)

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated

```
final public function getMedicarePolicies(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $data = MedicareAdvantage::with([
        'features' => static function (BelongsToMany $query) use ($request) {
            $query->select('id', 'feature_name')->whereIn('id', $request->input('features') ?? []);
        },
        'company' => static function (BelongsTo $query) use ($request) {
            $query->select('id', 'company_logo', 'company_name')->whereIn('id', $request->input('companies') ?? []);
        },
        'medicareAdvantagePlan' => static function (BelongsTo $query) use ($request) {
            $query->select('id', 'medicare_advantage_plan_type')->whereIn('id', $request->input('plans') ?? []);
        }
    ])->select('id', 'name', 'monthly_premium', 'primary_doctor_co_pay', 'specialist_co_pay', 'company_id')->get();
    return response()->json($data, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I managed to solve this anyways. Here's the solution:

```
$data = MedicareAdvantage::with('features', 'medicareAdvantagePlan', 'company')
    ->whereHas('features', static function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
        $query->select('id', 'feature_name')->where(static function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            if ($request->input('features') !== null) {
                $query->whereIn('id', $request->input('features'));
            }
        });
    })
    ->whereHas('medicareAdvantagePlan', static function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
        $query->select('id', 'medicare_advantage_plan_type')->where(static function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            if ($request->input('plans') !== null) {
                $query->whereIn('id', $request->input('plans'));
            }
        });
    })
    ->whereHas('company', static function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
        $query->select('id', 'company_name', 'company_logo')->where(static function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            if ($request->input('companies') !== null) {
                $query->whereIn('id', $request->input('companies'));
            }
        });
    })
    ->select('id', 'name', 'monthly_premium', 'primary_doctor_co_pay', 'specialist_co_pay')->get();
```

Comment: Maybe add scopes to simplify these types of queries.

Comment: What ate these? :)